# List of Dates in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying generate a list of future dates, every month for 12 months, using a batch script. I'm hoping for an output dates like this (the first group being the month):

```
02-23-2018
03-23-2018
04-23-2018
05-23-2018
06-23-2018
07-23-2018
08-23-2018
09-23-2018
10-23-2018
11-23-2018
12-23-2018
01-23-2019
02-23-2019
```

I'll use these future dates as part of another script. Here is what I've got so far, but doesnt seem to output variables in the loop correctly?

Unless someone has something similar already that will calculate future dates?

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET DATE_MONTH = 
SET DATE_DAY = 
SET DATE_YEAR = 


: ESTABLISH INITIAL TOKENS
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ('date /t') DO (SET /a DATE_DAY_RAW = %%b)
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ('date /t') DO (SET /a DATE_MONTH_RAW = %%a)
FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ('date /t') DO (SET /a DATE_YEAR_RAW = %%c)

: REMOVE LEADING ZERO
SET char = %DATE_MONTH_RAW:~0,1%
SET DATE_MONTH_RAW = %char:~1%
if [!char!] EQU [0] SET DATE_MONTH_RAW = !DATE_MONTH_RAW:~1!  

: LOOP THROUGH 12 MONTHS OF DATES

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,12) DO (

    : CORRECT LEADING MONTHS
    SET DATE_MONTH = 00!DATE_MONTH_RAW!
    SET DATE_MONTH = !DATE_MONTH:~-2!

    : CORRECT LEADING DAYS
    SET DATE_DAY =00!DATE_DAY_RAW!
    SET DATE_DAY =!DATE_DAY:~-2!

    : CORRECT YEARS
    SET DATE_YEAR = !DATE_YEAR_RAW!

    : OUTPUT
    ECHO Date now: !DATE_MONTH!-!DATE_DAY!-!DATE_YEAR!


    : INCREMENT MONTH FOR NEXT LOOP
    SET /a DATE_MONTH_RAW = !DATE_MONTH_RAW! + 1

    : CORRECT YEAR
    IF "!DATE_MONTH_RAW!" == "12" (SET /a DATE_MONTH_RAW = 1)

)
```

Comment: Is it doing some things correctly, or is it outputting nothing at all? Just at an initial glance, I notice you have a space between the variable name and the `=` in your `set` statement, which means that you're creating variables with names like `%DATE_MONTH %`.

Comment: Why use three `FOR` commands when you can just use one?

Comment: As @SomethingDark has pointed out to you.  Batch files are not free form like some other languages.  Spaces will bite you in the butt left and right.

Comment: Looks like you are going to a lot of work to mess up a perfectly good date string.  Why would you change the year 12 to 1?  It's unlikely you'll ever encounter the year 12, do you know something about time that we don't?

Comment: So what do you want it to do for short months if it's run on Jan 31? Some months don't have a 31'st day.

Comment: @SomethingDark thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @jwdonahue i fixed the year. that should really be months. so if it increments the month, and the month is more than 12 (because there is no 13th month), it should reset to 1 (Jan), and it should increment the year by one.

Comment: @Ourx, What about short months?

Comment: i've updated the expected output too now

Comment: @jwdonahue yes you're right, it should work for short months too. So today's date + 30 days, the continue for 12 months.

Comment: @Squashman you're right, could optimise that to only one FOR command

Answer (score 0):

Batch has no date/time calculation methods. You can write it yourself (there are several examples here on SO), but better use Powershell to do it for you.

This gets twelve dates from a defined day with a distance of 30 days between them (that's what I read from your comments)

(Note: some months could be skipped or occure twice)

```
@echo off
rem setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "datum=30.01.2017"  REM this format is due to my localization

for /l %%d in (0,1,11) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell "(get-date('%datum%')).AddDays(+%%d*30).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')"') do echo %%a
)
```

If you really want to work "from today", replace `(get-date('%datum%'))` with just `(get-date)`